# HashSet clone() method

Tags: java, collections, clone

I have created a clone of the existing HashSet using clone() and then comparing their references like below:

```
HashSet<Employee> h = new HashSet<>();
HashSet<Employee> h1=(HashSet<Employee>) h.clone();
System.out.println(h==h1);
```

OUTPUT:

```
false
```

Shouldn't this be true since we are creating shallow copies?

Comment: A shallow copy is not a reference copy.

Comment: If you want to copy the reference, just do `HashSet<Employee> h1 = h;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`HashSet` overrides](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java) the [`clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#clone()) method of [`Object` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone())

```
The general intent is that, for any object x, the expression:  
  x.clone() != x

will be true, and that the expression:
  x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass()

will be true, but these are not absolute requirements. While it is typically the case that:
  x.clone().equals(x)
will be true, this is not an absolute requirement.
```

By convention, the **object returned by this method should be** **independent of this object** (which is being cloned).

In Java, `==` checks for references not objects so, `h==h1` is `false` in your case.

Comment: But in deep copy as well we create new objects. How does it then defer from shallow because in both we create new objects

Comment: @ghostrider: to answer your question here is the link [deep copy and shallow copy](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deep-shallow-lazy-copy-java-examples/). I hope you doubts will be cleared after reading this article.

Answer (score 1):

In java == for objects check if the object its the exact same object.

And if you go and check the clone method:

```
public Object clone() {
    try {
        HashSet<E> newSet = (HashSet<E>) super.clone();
        newSet.map = (HashMap<E, Object>) map.clone();
        return newSet;
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        throw new InternalError(e);
    }
}
```

It easy to see it is creating a new object. So now you have TWO different objects that are shallowly equal

Comment: But in deep copy as well we create new objects. How does it then defer from shallow because in both we create new objects.